# Getting attachment from Outlook and placing in the body of a new Email after Formatting

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

This is essentially what I am trying to do...

1. search for a specific email by subject name
2. get the attachment to that email ( the attachment is an excel sheet of raw data)
3. run a formatting subroutine from another module on the excel attachment
4. place the newly formatted attachment to the body of a new email
5. Send the new email out to the client

I need help with steps 3 & 4.

```
Option Explicit
Sub sendEmail()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMi As MailItem
Dim olAtt As Attachment
Dim MyPath As String
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
MyPath = "C:\Users\(Me)\Desktop\"

For i = Fldr.Items.count To 1 Step -1
    Set olMi = Fldr.Items(i)
    If InStr(1, olMi.Subject, "[The email I'm looking for by subject]") > 0 Then
         For Each olAtt In olMi.Attachments
                olAtt.Module2.Format   '<--- this is where i try to do step 3
                olAtt.SaveAsFile MyPath & "NewSheet" & ".xls"             
        With olEmail
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Body = olAtt.Range   '<----this is where i try to do step 4
            .To = "someone@something.com"
            .Subject = "Tester"
            .send
        End With

        Next olAtt
        olMi.Save
    End If
Next i

Set olAtt = Nothing
Set olMi = Nothing
Set Fldr = Nothing
Set MoveToFldr = Nothing
Set olNs = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: "run a formatting subroutine' does what *exactly* ?  What is the attachment here?

Comment: the subroutine simply formats the excel document to look presentable. The attachment is an excel sheet with raw data on it so I use a subroutine that formats it the way I want it to look.

Comment: You will likely need to save each attachment to disk in order to "reformat" it, but without more detail (such as the code for `Module2.Format`) it's impossible to make any more detailed suggestions.

Comment: The Module2.Format subroutine already works. I use it daily with a ctrl+F hot  key that auto formats the file i have open. Now I'm just trying to make it call the subroutine without me having to open the file my self and press the hot key set for it. Sorry for not being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).

I have noticed the following code:

```
For i = Fldr.Items.count To 1 Step -1
 Set olMi = Fldr.Items(i)
  If InStr(1, olMi.Subject, "[The email I'm looking for by subject]") > 0 Then
```

Do not iterate over all items in the folder. Instead, you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to get items which corresponds to your conditions. You can read more about them in the following articles in MSDN. Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

> .Body = olAtt.Range   '<----this is where i try to do step 4

The Outlook object model provides three main ways for working with item bodies:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Inspector class returns an instance of the Word Document which represents the message body. So, **you can use the Word object model do whatever you need with the message body**.

See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will look into this.